# Find system of equation with infinite solutons?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$2x+7y-5z=0\\
5x-2y+6z=1\\
7x+5y+z=1$$

Answer should be in the form of (blank,blank,z) where z is any real number.

Comment: What is your question? Where are you having difficulties?

Comment: I need the solution to this question please, I don't know how to solve it. Attempting to use the Gauss-Jordan method of elimination and I don't know how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: The last equation is just the sum of the first and second equations. So you have only two equations in three unknowns

Comment: Please refer to the form of the answer (blank,blank,z) where z is any real number. Thank you.

Comment: Now you can suppose $z$ as a free variable say $r$ and solve the first and second equations in terms of $r$

Answer (score 1):

Form your augmented matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&7&\!\!-5&0\\
5&\!\!-2&6&1\\
7&5&1&1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_1\to\frac12R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac72&\!\!-\frac52&0\\
5&\!\!-2&6&1\\
7&5&1&1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{\begin{cases}R_2-5R_1\\R_3-7R_1\end{cases}}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac72&\!\!-\frac52&0\\
0&\!-\frac{39}2&\frac{37}2&1\\
0&\!-\frac{39}2&\frac{37}2&1\end{pmatrix}$$

You can delete the third row as it is identical to the second one, and now from this second row we get that

$$-\frac{39}2y=1-\frac{37}2z\implies y=\frac{37z-2}{39}$$

and then the first one gives us

$$x+\frac72y=\frac52z\implies x=\frac52z-\frac72\frac{37z-2}{39}=-\frac{32}{39}z+\frac7{39}$$

and the parametric, and rather ugly, form of the solution to the original system is

$$\left\{\;\left(-\frac{32}{39}z+\frac7{39}\;,\;\;\frac{37z-2}{39}\;,\;\;z\right)\;|:\;\;z\in\Bbb R\;\right\}$$